# Why string type is not converting to int type?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I want to add two numbers. I am getting values from button in my textbox. I also succeeded in splitting string into substrings and store values of these substrings in variables. But i am not able to convert string type to integer type. That results in concatenation not in addtion.
Note :
I am using MVC to perform this task. And in model value1 and value2 is string type in model 
Here is my code snippet:

```
if (button == "1"){
    if (model.textBox == "" || model.textBox == null || model.textBox.ToLower().Contains("please enter value")){
        model.textBox = "1";
    } else {
        model.textBox += "1";
    }
}
if (button == "2") {
    if (model.textBox == "" && model.textBox == null) {
        model.textBox = "2";
    } else {
        model.textBox += "2";
    }
if (button == "+") {
    if (model.textBox == "" && model.textBox == null){
        model.errormsg = "Please enter a number ";
    } else {
        model.textBox += "+";
    }
if (button == "=") {
    if (model.textBox.Contains("+")) {
        model.value1 = (model.textBox.Split('+'))[0];
        int value1 = int.Parse(model.value1);
        model.value2 = (model.textBox.Split('+'))[1];
        int value2 = int.Parse(model.value2);
         model.textBox = model.value1 + model.value2;
    }
return View(model);
```

Comment: Your adding the model values (which are typeof `string`), it the `int` values you declare - `model.textBox = (value1 + value2).ToString();`

Answer (score 5):

If i got you correctly all you need to do is:

```
model.textBox = (value1 + value2).ToString();
```

Comment: Already my value are of string type. I want to convert them to integer. So that values must be added not concatenated.

Comment: Yes, but value1 is in and also value2 - after you added them it makes on the sum the ToSring() action.

Comment: Please provide me some more help and detail. I am not getting the desired result. It still concatenate the value 1 and value2, not adding value1 and value2.

Comment: please tell me where do you see the concatination? in which part or code snippet?

Comment: if (button == "=")
                {
                    if (model.textBox.Contains("+")) {
                        model.value1 = (model.textBox.Split('+'))[0];
                        
                        model.value2 = (model.textBox.Split('+'))[1];
                        model.textBox = (model.value1 + model.value2).ToString();}                                                                         this code snippet gives me concatenation result:  if  entered values are 1 and 2 then result would be 3 but this gives me result 12

Comment: aaaaaa.... don't write model.value1, write value1!!! :-) and the same for model.value2 -> to value2 (in the last code part)

Answer (score 1):

`model.textBox` is of type `string`, so, when you do `model.textBox += "1";` the only possible operation is concatenation.

To add them as integers you first need to convert your `textBox` to `int`.

Something like the following will work:

```
model.textBox = (int.Parse(model.textBox) + 1).ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `int.Parse(textBox.Text)`.

It will crash if there is a non-numeric character in the string, but that's nothing a try-catch block won't fix.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

```
 if (button == "=") {
    if (model.textBox.Contains("+")) {
        model.value1 = (model.textBox.Split('+'))[0];
        int value1 = int.Parse(model.value1);
        model.value2 = (model.textBox.Split('+'))[1];
        int value2 = int.Parse(model.value2);
         model.textBox = model.value1 + model.value2;
    }
```

Replace above code snippet with below code snippet:

```
if (button == "=")
            {
                if (model.textBox.Contains("+"))
                {
                    model.value1 = (model.textBox.Split('+'))[0];

                    model.value2 = (model.textBox.Split('+'))[1];

                    model.textBox1 = (int.Parse(model.value1) + int.Parse(model.value2)).ToString();


                }
```